Error with LazyColumn: "Asking for intrinsic measurements of SubcomposeLayout layouts is not supported"
I'm getting the following error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Asking for intrinsic measurements of SubcomposeLayout layouts is not supported. This includes components that are built on top of SubcomposeLayout, such as lazy lists, BoxWithConstraints, TabRow, etc. To mitigate this:
if intrinsic measurements are used to achieve 'match parent' sizing,, consider replacing the parent of the component with a custom layout which controls the order in which children are measured, making intrinsic measurement not needed
adding a size modifier to the component, in order to fast return the queried intrinsic measurement.

This is my code:
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight()) {
    itemsIndexed(summaryList) { _, item ->
        Column(modifier = Modifier.fillParentMaxHeight()) {
            Text(text = item.displayName, style = TextStyle(fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold))
            Text(text = item.noteDesc)
            Divider()
        }
    }
}


It's working for me, I cannot reproduce the problem. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Use fillMaxWidth() instead of fillParentMaxHeight()

Still my app is crashed. I am using using lazy column inside Column and above lazycolumn I am using another composable.

give fix size to your inner column
